# Need for assumption of continuity of the distribution

Tags: nonparametric

In non parametric Inference what is the need to make the assumption that the underlying distribution of the random variable under consideration is absolutely continuous?

Comment: Many nonparametric procedures are based on ranks. If there are tied values among the data, the interpretation of ranks may not be straightforward. So often the requirement of continuity is intended to avoid ties. In the computer age, many nonparametric procedures have been programmed to correct for the presence of (at least modest nrs of) ties. What counts as a 'tie' may differ from one proc to another. (In a one-sample test, values with the same abs value may be considered tied; in a multi-sample test, 'ties' may refer to identical values in different samples; all prevented by continuity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment continued:*  In the real world there is no such thing as
continuous data because we must round observations to *some* number
of decimal places. The following demonstration shows that the
degree of rounding can influence the results of the 2-sample Wilcoxon
(rank sum) test.

Originally, data are simulated as two samples of size 20 from Laplace 
distributions with unit scale parameter
and a difference 1.1 between sample means, rounded to 3 places. 
(See 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Relation_to_the_exponential_distribution) on Laplace.) There are no ties, so that the data are 'continuous' for purposes of the 
2-sample Wilcoxon test. It finds a significant difference at the 5% level.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rexp(20) - rexp(20)
x2 = rexp(20) - rexp(20) + 1.1
x = round(c(x1, x2),3)
gp = as.factor(rep(1:2, each=20))
length(unique(x))
[1] 40
```

[image]

```
wilcox.test(x ~ gp)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x by gp
W = 123, p-value = 0.03752
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

However, if data are *rounded to integers,* then there are many ties (only 8
uniquely different observations among the 40). Thus, the 2-sample Wilcoxon
test (as implemented in the 'base' of R) fails to reject at the 5% level.

```
length(unique(round(x)))
[1] 8
wilcox.test(round(x) ~ gp)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  round(x) by gp
W = 139.5, p-value = 0.09627
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2,  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

*Note:* To be fair: the discrepancy in results seen above is not *just* a matter of ties disturbing the distribution theory of ranks in the Wilcoxon test. The additional rounding to integers results in a serious
loss of information. These are not ideal data for use with t-tests,
but a Welch t test on the original data finds a significant difference
at the 5% level (p-value 0.03) while the a Welch test on integer-rounded data does not
(p-value 0.08). Ordinarily, t tests are much less affected by rounding than are Wilcoxon tests.

Comment: I am specifically interested in why the continuity assumption is required in the derivation of the null distributions of test statistics.

Comment: For the Wilcoxon one and two-sample tests, Kruskal-Wallis and Friedman tests, null distributions are based on ranks and continuity prevents ties. For larger sample sizes there are useful normal or chi-squared approximations to the _discrete_ null distributions and those distributions happen to be continuous, but that is another issue. // If you have _one specific_ nonparametric test in mind, then maybe a new question about derivation of its null distribution would get an answer that would interest you. But I think I have answered this question and given a clarifying example. Happy Holidays!

Comment: For a start, maybe read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) for a description of the null distribution of the 1-sample Wilcoxon test and the usual normal approximation.